# Angularjs lightbox custom close in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularbootstrap-lightbox

I want to have a custom close in controller that when I click the OK in alert it will close the lightbox also but I dont know how to make it. This is the link

[Lightbox](https://compact.github.io/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/demo3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alert box doesn't return value on click function. what u need is a confirm box

```
var r = confirm("message");
if (r) {
   Lightbox.closeModal()
}
```

Also, inject the `Lightbox` to the controller.

Comment: ahh yes but what if ill change the alert box with custom modal. Still I dont know what to put in `//code for closing the lightbox`

Comment: thanks for this one in their sample they didnt stated this closeModal();

Comment: yep, I had to dig into their library to find that :D